# Replacing Messaging with relational database

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, amqp

I am having a scenario where my web application wants to raise some events. Single event will lead to multiple actions ( i.e. pub-sub model in messaging). Now I have 2 choices, first is to send a direct AMQP publish call to messaging engine ( in my case it will be RabbitMQ) .

Other option is to persist the event in DB(mysql) table and then implement listeners on this table to query events and then send these to MQ.

I want minimum impact on my web application flow ( i.e. i want to spend minimum time possible to raise a event ( either db save or AMQP publish).

I am inclined towards db as i have to minimum error handling ( as probability of db connection going down is very less and at that time whole application will be down so eventually no data/events loss).  On the other hand If i go with direct AMQP call, i need to handle errors at my end ( probability of mq connection going down looks very much probable).

Any suggestions are much appreciable.

Comment: There might be a lot of different answers based on personal experience, synthetic test or just opinion, but each case is unique and you have to pick the solution that fits your needs by yourself.

Comment: @zaq178miami I understand, hence i want to know the people's experience plus their findings.

Comment: Every experience is unique and really depends on application needs and loads. There are tons of pros and cons, so you this question can't get a strict and definitive answer. It just produces to a heap of primary opinion-based answers, that's all. Maybe it's not just a SO format.

Answer (score 0):

In the db approach you have a more complicated integration scenario, since you introduce other systems and mechanisms (the db, listeners) in-between. There are more points of failure in this scenario, but they concern the event handling part of the process, not the event raising.

If it is critical for you to achieve minimum impact on the frontend I think that your approach is sound and the extra complexity is worth it.

A hint for the DB: It might prove better to design the database in a minimalistic manner, with as little as possible coupling between it and the process, so you can avoid any changes to the schema if you ever need to change the event format for example. This will lead to more maintainability.

Comment: In my application i already have a db connection, and as you said i will have extra complexity to handle the listeners but that can always be separate from event raising. My only doubt is about stability of MQ connection vs DB connection. As i understand db connection is much more reliable and probability of db connection going down is very less as compare to MQ hence probability of data loss is less (if db connection goes down, my application flow can't even run)but with mq connection going down, i need to handle failure scenarios and still an edge case can be missed and data loss is possible